# Why does Django template script src only works if hard-coded?

Tags: python, django

In order to avoid mixing non-SSL and SSL content, I want to use a relative path for my Javascript file.  In settings.py, I have defined JS_ROOT = "/path/js/".

In my html file, the following line results in no mixed content warning:

```
<script src="/path/js/Foo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This line gives a mixed content warning:

```
<script src="{{ JS_ROOT }}Foo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any explanation?

Comment: Is `Foo.js` available via both HTTPS and HTTP?

Comment: with the latter (the one that gives mixed content warning), what HTML gets generated?  (i.e is the src /path/js/Foo.js or http(s)://path/js/Foo.js ? )

Comment: Hmm.  The version with {{ JS_ROOT }} appends the "/path/js/Foo.js" to the complete current URL.  The other version (which works correctly), appends to just the hostname.  It looks like the Django template tag is not working as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that my problem was that I was not returning JS_ROOT correctly as part of my request context.  Now that I include it in my context_processors.py and have the context_instance as part of my response, it works.